# Engintron: Nginx couldn't start

Tags: nginx, cpanel, whm

I have a Cpanel/WHM server with Nginx installed as reverse proxy (with default Nginx manager), so i tried to replace Nginx with Engintron.
I installed Engintron and uninstalled Nginx via Cpanel Nginx manager.
As a result i got website not working and Nginx couldn't start (status from WHM  Engintron page), so i should reinstall Nginx?
I don't know if Engintron contains already Nginx or not
I tried to reinstall Nginx and website work again, but i don't know if Engintron is serving the website or Nginx

Answer (score 1):

Engintron contains nginx installation within their script. So if you install only engintron, it will be default instead nginx in reverse proxy mode with apache.

You can check your nginx installed configuration file location by
sudo nginx -t

(it will show location of configuration file along with testing the same).

See if the nginx configuration file matches the engintron configuration file or not. If you are confused here also then run
$ sudo nginx -T

this will dump the output of configuration file which you may tally with Engintron config file.

Last option would be to uninstall both the nginx and make a clean installation of Engintron.

Comment: I reinstalled Nginx from Cpanel Nginx manager and reinstalled Engintron, 
nginx -t  gives nginx: command not found

Comment: I reinstalled Nginx (not Engintron) and now nginx -t gives nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

Comment: Please check if engintron is also using same nginx.conf file (I believe so). If it's the same file, then you may keep the setup as it is. Engintron basically helps configuring nginx in a better way and providing rest other services configuration / reboot service option at one place. 

In case you still have doubt, why not remove engintron and nginx and then simply install engintron only which will itself install nginx too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run these commands first:

```
/usr/sbin/nginx -s stop
/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/restartsrv_nginx start
```

If the problem still exists, Uninstall Nginx and all Ruby packages from EasyApache via WHM and reinstall Nginx again.